# I want to make validation for same user assigned using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am a beginner and I am trying to make validation for the user assigned when I assign the same user again when I submit so the error message should be shown, **this user is already assigned** please help me how to do this? thanks.

**Controller**

```
      public function adduseraction(REQUEST $request) { 

    //  Users_permissions::where('user_id',$request->userid)->get()- 
    //  >pluck('user_Access_id');

      $useradd=$request->get('userid');
      $checkid=$request->get('multiusersid');

      $array = array();
      foreach($checkid as $id){
      $array[] = array('user_id'=>$useradd,'user_Access_id'=>$id);
       }

       $user=Users_permissions::insert($array);    
      return redirect('admin')->with('success', 'Users has been assigned');
       }
```

**html view**

```
    <form action="{{route('adduseraction')}}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <label>Select User</label>
    <select name="userid" class="form-control" id="typeofworkday">
    <option>Select User</option>
    @foreach($users as  $user)
    <option  value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>           
    @endforeach
    </select>
    </div>
    <br>  <br>  <br>
    <div class="card-body">
    <label>Select Muliple User or One</label>
    <!-- Minimal style -->
    <div class="row">
    @foreach($users as  $user)
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" name="multiusersid[]"  value=" 
   {{$user->id}}" class="form-check-input" >
    <h5 style="position:relative;left:10px;">{{$user->name}}</h5>
    </div>
    <!-- checkbox -->
    </div>
    @endforeach
    </div>
    <!-- /.card-body --> 
    </div>
    <br><br><br><br>
    <div class="card-footer">
    <button type="submit" name="btnsubmit" class="btn btn-primary col- 
    md-2 center">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can do something like below

First check does user already exists in the table and if exists return redirect with the error message or else insert the data

```
  public function adduseraction(Request $request) { 

 $isUserAvailable = Users_permissions::where('user_id',$request->userid)->get()- >pluck('user_Access_id');
//If user already exists 
if($isUserAvailable) {
   return redirect('admin')->with('error', 'Users has been assigned');
}else{
  $useradd=$request->get('userid');
  $checkid=$request->get('multiusersid');

  $array = array();
  foreach($checkid as $id){
  $array[] = array('user_id'=>$useradd,'user_Access_id'=>$id);
   }

   $user=Users_permissions::insert($array);    
  return redirect('admin')->with('success', 'Users has been assigned');
   }
```

}

Comment: let me know if anything else you wanted

Comment: please can you check the last line is it right? I am facing unspected error thanks.

 return redirect('admin')->with('success', ' return redirect('admin')->with('success', 'Users has been assigned');');

Comment: Please check the answer now

Comment: actually when adding a new user so the message is showing return error popup

Comment: What do you mean by new user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208307/discussion-between-nipun-tharuksha-and-zubair).